# How to fix real time congested network. (JITTER)

Tags: cisco, routing, switch, router, packet-tracer

How ever I'm using packet tracer for confidential Purposes. In the image below The PC's are 192.168.1.0 network and the server is 192.168.2.2, the pc's are requesting data in the server HTTPS every Point one seconds .1 in 1000mb size file. so the question is how can I still give service without congesting the network,In this image we can see the latency become higher and also a packet loss. what I want is no packet loss and low latency, literally avoiding JITTER NETWORK.

Update: in the picture all links are now GIGABIT two switch was unnecessary but the switch only have 12 ports but i need more than one so I add one more,  the system no longer suffer packet loss however the jitter or  high latency still occur, ping is around 50-200ms, were getting close people.

[image]

[image]

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/vpqaag1aaclxfkw/packet%20tracer.pkt?dl=0 here is the actual fie, feel free to see and do solution.

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you can provide your own answer and accept it.

Answer (score 1):

You have multiple things that could cause this:

- Daisy-chaining PCs will be a problem since they are not optimized for
  switching.  The PCs closest to the switch will need to handle their
  own traffic as well as all the traffic from the PCs behind them.
- You can cause congestion if the uplink from the switch is the
  same speed as each of the links from the PCs feeding it.  Multiple,
  saturated access links simply cannot be served at line-speed by a single
  uplink at the same speed as the access links without congestion. The switch uplink needs to be at least as fast as the aggregated access links' speeds.
- You should check the load on your router since it may have gigabit
  ethernet ports, but that doesn't mean it can packet switch at
  line-speed, especially with multiple services running on it.
- The link to the server needs to be at least as fast as the aggregated access links' speeds.

You need to figure out what is causing the congestion and remediate it, and there may be multiple problems that need to be resolved. That may involve redesigning your network, replacing underpowered equipment, upgrading link speeds, etc.

Comment: Hmp. . you seem to make sense. I'll try.

Comment: By the way they're not daisy chains pc's, they're just divergent

Comment: Your solution had given me improvement to my network only one thing left is the jitter or high latency, how can i fix that?

Comment: Based on your original diagram, if you fix the congestion the jitter (changes in latency) will naturally dissipate. If you had a much larger network, or involved the Internet, you could only do so much about jitter..

Answer (score 0):

You may want to implement Quality of Service to limit the usage of bandwith.
By using traffic shaping you would be able to limit the bandwith usage.

Comment: Then my service would not be as advertise, I advertise 1Gb in every .1 sec. the question is how to handle the congestion. Thank you for answering though.

Comment: If you need every client to transmit at 1Gbit/sec speed you would need to have a link with higher throughput.

From what you have written I understand that you have a server with a 1Gbit/sec Uplink and clients need to access data at 1Gbit/sec - is that correct?

Comment: Yep. and that 1gbit/.1 sec(point one sec)

Comment: Also switches on the other hand have a maximum 100mb/s in FULL DUPLEX.

Answer (score 0):

[image]
The answer:

-All links and ports must be gigabit

-The switch to the router link must be trunk all else must be access

-Switch connected to PC's must be Full duplex and Speed or bandwidth is set auto.

-Tx ring limit must be 5 (higher ring = higher latency)